# Console log behaviour regarding array in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

What am i missing here? Cant get it why my console behaves differently depending on either while loop is there or not?

```
function findPath(){
  var openArr = [];
  var closeArr = [];
  var morefun = {};
  var morefun1 = {};
  var morefun2 = {};
  morefun.f = 1;
  morefun1.f = 2;
  morefun2.f = 3;
  openArr.push(morefun1);
  openArr.push(morefun2);
  openArr.push(morefun);
  console.log(Array.isArray(openArr));
  console.log(openArr);
  console.log(openArr.length);

    while (openArr.length){
    var current = openArr.pop();
    closeArr.push(current);
    }
}
findPath();
```

Im getting from console.log(openArr)

```
 [Object, Object,Object]
 length: 0  // when while loop is there.
```

And getting

```
 [Object, Object,Object]
 0:Object
 1:Object
 2:Object
 length:3 // without while loop
```

It doesent seem to be Chrome only thing as my Firefox console shows similar results - when i click on an array for details i get length:0 with loop and length:3 w/o. Am i missing smth with execution order?

Comment: Is this all your code? I get the same result either way.

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: Sorry ... my bad. This may explain why. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23392650/4602928

Answer (score 2):

When you write something to the console, it creates a string that represents the state of the object at that time. However, it also stores a reference to the actual object and that's what you're presented with in the console.

Expanding that reference shows it's actual state where as the string shows it's state *at the time of printing*. If you want to see the complete state of an array with each `console.log` you could convert it to JSON.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(openArr, null, 2));
```

Example:

```js
var arr = [{ n: 1 }, { n: 2 }, { n: 3 }];
console.log(arr); // [Object, Object, Object]
arr.pop();
// Expand the array and you'll only see 2 elements

var arr2 = arr.slice(0);
// To see the full state of the array, serialize it
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2, null, 2)); // [ { "n": 2 }, { "n": 3 } ]
console.log(arr2); // [Object, Object]
arr.pop();
// Expand the array and you'll only see 1 element
```